# Change element height angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code below, that I thought will work. but it doesn't

```
'use strict';

angular.module('remnantApp')
  .directive('bigDiv', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<div style="height: {{height}}, background-color: black;">Hello</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.height = angular.element(window).height();
      }
    };
  });
```

Please help

Comment: You  thought will work. but it doesn't ? Ok. Say that. But put more explainations please. What is currently not working ? Have you got some error thrown ? Help us to help you..

Comment: sorry, yeah. I didn't get any error at all.  However, I thought that the div element height will change as that directive loads. but it didn't.

Comment: Ok, so. Please put your HTML complete markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`templateUrl` should be `template` as you are using inline template, Also the dynamica style could be render using `ng-style` then template becomes like `ng-style="{height: height + \'px\' }"`

**Markup**

```
<big-div><big-div>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('remnantApp',[])
  .directive('bigDiv', function ($timeout,$window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<div class="big-div" ng-style="{height: height + \'px\' }" style="background-color: black;">Hello</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.height = $window.innerHeight; //without jQuery
        //other alternative would be
        //element.find('.big-div').css(height, scope.height);
      }
    };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TsnH00jzDS1yiITHhhXr?p=preview)

Comment: sorry, yeah i fixed that. it still doesn't work. it wasn't the original problem

Comment: @ChristianSakai then could you explain what is the problem?

Comment: sorry. yeah. I tried to change the element height using scope, but it didn't change.

Comment: @ChristianSakai look at the other alterative which I updated in code..Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use `ng-style` when using dynamic style attributes:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('remnantApp')
  .directive('bigDiv', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<div ng-style="styles">Hello</div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.styles = {
          height: angular.element(window).height(),
          'background-color': 'black'
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: yeah this one works too. I didn't know that there is a ng-style in angular.  Thanks!